# Best Book For poles and residues

Tags: complex-analysis, reference-request

Hi guys i need you to help me choose a book where i can easly understand singularities , poles and residues , thk you.

Comment: To get good answers, I think you should at least explain what your background is.

Comment: i'mstudying at 2 year computer eng. i have done real analysis , (integral limits etc , double integral differential equations, differentials form, fluxus , fouries , laplace etc but i want to understand deep and well this argoument to do good exercises

Answer (score 1):

Reinhold Remmert, in his *Theory of Complex Functions*, explains these topics very well.